# Grails not honoring DB connection pool settings

Tags: grails, tomcat7, connection-pooling

I'm running with Grails 2.5.3 (this problem was observed in 2.4.4 as well), and although I have overridden some of the default connection pool settings in DataSource.groovy, it doesn't appear to be using them.  We noticed our idle connections grow to ~200 despite setting maxIdle to 20.  To illustrate, I ran the following JMX commands:

```
$>get -b grails.dataSource:application=ts,dataSource=default,type=ConnectionPool MinIdle
#mbean = grails.dataSource:application=ts,dataSource=default,type=ConnectionPool:
MinIdle = 11;

$>get -b grails.dataSource:application=ts,dataSource=default,type=ConnectionPool NumIdle
#mbean = grails.dataSource:application=ts,dataSource=default,type=ConnectionPool:
NumIdle = 10;
```

An excerpt from DataSource.groovy:

```
development {
    development_base.call()
}

def development_base = {
    dataSource {
        url = <my url>
        properties {
            maxActive = 100
            maxIdle = 20
            minIdle = 11
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=300000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=300000
            numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
            testOnBorrow=true
            testWhileIdle=true
            testOnReturn=true
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            validationQueryTimeout = 10
            removeAbandoned = true
            removeAbandonedTimeout = 120
            logAbandoned = true
            abandonWhenPercentageFull = 60
            suspectTimeout = 60
        }
    }
    ...
```

I also tried changing the validationQuery to something invalid ("SELECT * from foo" since foo does not exist), but was able to still run queries fine.

Note that I tried moving this config to BootStrap.groovy & resources.groovy, but it appeared to have the same effect.

Comment: how are you using that closure in DataSource.groovy?

Comment: It's being called by: 

development {
        development_base.call()
    }

Comment: try setting the `delegate` before calling: `development{ dev_base.delegate = delegate; dev_base.call() }`

Comment: Same result. It's definitely using the right URL which is set in that block. You can see from the JMX above that it's taking the setting, it's just not using it. Plus as I mentioned I also tried the BootStrap & resources files.

Comment: did you use `environments{}`?

Comment: Yes, I didn't think it was important to go into that level of detail.

Comment: Did you find any solutions? I'm experiencing the same issue